# Nullpointerexception error on android studio SDK

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a simple social media app using java and node.js framework, however, i am frequently getting nullpointerexception error. Initally, i thought it was something wrong with my java code but when i debug my code using breakpoint, it shows some error on the sdk java file(contextWrapper.java).
[image: error image]

I want to know If this is normal or there's something wrong with my sdk. If my sdk has problem then would you please tell me how to fix this. Moreover, i have already tried reinstalling android studio, however, this doesn't fix the error. I am tired of searching solution.Please help me on this.

Comment: Your screenshot has nothing to do with NullPointerException.

Comment: Something must be wrong with your SDK. Is it properly set in File->Project structure->Sdk location?

Comment: try to build your project first, some library are missings.

Comment: make sure you have required sdk i.e., 30 in your case downloaded in studio.